# PLEX unRAID, how to setup?

Tags: linux, networking, nas, plex

I'm trying to setup PLEX on my unRAID server I just built, I have not used PLEX or unRAID before, I am following [these instructions](http://dalladay.net/17/getting-started-with-unraid-6-3-5-and-plex/)  have also watch various videos, but at the end of step 3 when I click apply after added my movie path, I just get an error.

My Path that I set:
[image]
The error I get:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the "&" symbol in the path, I had to remove it and name it MoviesSeries instead.

Answer provide by: https://forums.lime-technology.com/topic/62043-installing-plex-media-server-unraid-os-635/